# Why are these @font-face declarations not loading anything?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I'm trying to import TTF fonts in a Chrome extension I'm working on, but the font-face rules I've written don't seem to be getting picked up by Chrome:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Montserrat-Regular'), url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('ttf');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Montserrat-Bold'), url('/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using Google Fonts to manage the font declaration CSS. See https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Montserrat

Comment: Since this is a Chrome extension, it's going to get used in scenarios with incomplete network access (such as behind a captive portal) - making it network-dependent via Google Fonts is less desirable than something local to the package. I'm vendoring the fonts into the downloaded package directly from https://github.com/google/fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike nearly every other font format in webfonts (which match the most common file extensions for the contained font), the format identifier for TTF fonts is `format('truetype')`, not `format('ttf')`.